# Minimization of the time it takes to preview a large beamertex file

Tags: beamer, compiling, texify

I have a very large beamer tex file which requires a long time to texify.  I want to make very minor changes and want to visualize these changes quickly.  Is there a way to texify only the changes that I made to speed up visualization (previews)?  Is there a way to preview single frame or a block of code only?

If not, what are other tips on how to speed up the texifying process and minimize the time it takes to preview my document?

Comment: Are you using a Makefile or something similar? Do you run bibtex and run pdflatex several times?

Comment: @Bichoy No... I simply run the "latex" command in TexShop.

Comment: Is there a way to configure what exactly this latex command does? Something like build configuration?

Comment: @Bichoy: I'm not sure.  I'm relatively new to latex in general, and I barely know how to use the program, much less configure it :)

Comment: During a latex compilation, latex itself is ran several times on the file. And if you have bibliography, the number of required runs increase. If you can search for how to configure TeXShop to make it just run latex once, you may cut this time by a factor of 4 or even more. Sorry, this is the best I can help with. I am an old school who uses latex from the command line.

Comment: I generally make individual frames in a separate file that has the same preamble as the main beamer file. When the frame is finished I paste the finalized code into the main file.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is a job for `\includeonlyframes`

A little example follows- note the use of `label`- you can try experimenting with

```
\includeonlyframes{lions,cows}
```

or

```
\includeonlyframes{cows}
```

for example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\includeonlyframes{lions,cows}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=lions]{Lions}
  Lions
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=zebras]{zebras}
  zebras
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[label=cows]{cows}
  cows
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot the ducks?! +1. :)